# Detecting a contract deployment, zero address?

Tags: go-ethereum

Can anyone help ?

I am trying to listen for a new contract deployed. I thought that contracts were sent to the zero address which means its a new contract deployment, although this is not working. Maybe I am doing something wrong ?

```
            for _, tx := range block.Transactions() {

                zeroed := util.IsZeroAddress(tx.Hash().Hex())

                if zeroed {
                    fmt.Println("We have a zero address!!!!")
                    fmt.Println("header", header.Hash().Hex())
                    fmt.Println("tx", tx.Hash().Hex())
                }
```

The above doesn't seem to work so I am obviously doing something wrong.

I am listening for new headers, then getting the block and then finally the transactions.

Does anybody know how I can confirm that one of the transaction is a new contract deployment ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this wont cover all instances of contract creation. Many contracts are created this way, by omitting the `to` address (hence it being 0x00...00), but many are also created by other contracs using the CREATE/CREATE2 opcodes. Uniswap exchange contracts, for example, are created by another contract, and not by omitting the `to` address in a transaction

This specific method isn't working because you aren't checking if the `to` address is all zeros, you're checking if the transaction *hash* is zero. Change the following to be the equivalent that gets the `to` address of the transaction:

```
util.IsZeroAddress(tx.Hash().Hex())
```

Comment: wow! Thanks, yep that was it. Silly mistake on my part BUT also, I was waiting to get a pancakeswap (which i assume is similar to uniswap as it was a fork) - and yep- i never got a zero address BUT the actual To() was nil :-)

I placed it into BSCScan and sure enough its a token - which is what I was looking for!

Thank you for all your help.